# Node JS - GraphQL - Elastic Search - Elasticsearch mapping does not contains info about is field plural or not

Tags: elasticsearch, graphql, express-graphql

Elasticsearch mapping does not contains info about is field plural or not. So propName is singular and returns value or first value from array. propNameA is plural and returns array of values.

I am sending an array of object but graphQL is not sending a array of object but just an single object.

Answer (score 0):

Got the answer, just add the following `pluralFields` to `graphql-compose-elasticsearch`

```
const UserTC = composeWithElastic({
  graphqlTypeName: 'UserES',
  elasticIndex: 'user',
  elasticType: 'user',
  elasticMapping: mapping,
  elasticClient: new elasticsearch.Client({
    host: 'http://localhost:9200',
    apiVersion: '5.0',
    log: 'trace',
  }),
  // elastic mapping does not contain information about is fields are arrays or not
  // so provide this information explicitly for obtaining correct types in GraphQL
  pluralFields: ['skills', 'languages'],
});
```

Reference: https://www.npmjs.com/package/graphql-compose-elasticsearch?activeTab=readme